# I am getting billed for AWS Elastic IPs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

EC2 pricing page says that Elastic IP addresses are free and I got the bill and I am being charged for Elastic IP Addresses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS EC2 Elastic IPs bandwidth usage and charges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051533/aws-ec2-elastic-ips-bandwidth-usage-and-charges)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do you have the Elastic IP address is associated with an EC2
   instance ?
2. if yes, is the instance associated with the Elastic IP
   address is running.
3. if yes, do the associated instance has only one
   Elastic IP address attached to it.

If any of the above is **false** you would be charged for it. The # of IP address is finite and this is a kind of fair use policy.

Comment: I had Elastic IP associated with more than 1 instance, so point 3 is false for me. Thanks I got the reason I was looking for.

Comment: Update. All IPv4 IPs are charged. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-public-ipv4-address-charge-public-ip-insights/

Answer (score 0):

If Your Elastic IP is unassigned you will be charged.

Please Make sure that;

An Elastic IP address doesn’t incur charges as long as the following conditions are true:

The Elastic IP address is associated with an EC2 instance.
The instance associated with the Elastic IP address is running.
The instance has only one Elastic IP address attached to it.

This is from AWS Pricing Documentation

Answer (score 0):

> An Elastic IP address is a reserved public IP address that you can
>   assign to any EC2 instance in a particular region, until you choose to
>   release it. To allocate an Elastic IP address to your account in a
>   particular region

AWS Charges you for every EIP you have which is not used (=not associated to any resource)

To release (=delete) an Elastic IP, follow these steps:

1. Go to the EC2 console
2. Under the Network & Security tab, choose
   Elastic IPs
3. Select the IP address you wish to remove
4. Click on actions and choose `Release Address`.

If the option `Release Address` is greyed out, it means that the IP address you've selected is still associated with a resource. Then you'll need to click on `Disassociate Address` first.